# How can read file in bash from last read location

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have log file which is updated contunuously.
I want to run cron job every 5 mins which read that file  and run awk command to send some metrics to cloudwatch.

Now i want to only read file where i left in last read operation.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to record the offset you were in at the end.

It would be easier with ksh93 or zsh which have builtin operators for that instead of bash.

For instance, with ksh93:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
file=/some/file.log
offset_file=$file.offset
offset=$(<"$offset_file")

{
  do-your-processing; ret=$?

  echo "$(<#((CUR)))" > "$offset_file" && exit "$ret"
} < "$file" <#((offset))
```

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system

file=/some/file.log
offset_file=$file.offset
offset=$(<$offset_file)

{
  sysseek offset || exit

  do-your-processing; ret=$?

  echo $((systell(0))) > $offset_file && exit $ret
} < $file
```

With `bash`, you could do most of the above and call `ksh93`, `zsh` or `perl` to do the seeking/telling:

```
#! /bin/bash -
file=/some/file.log
offset_file=$file.offset
offset=$(<"$offset_file")

seek() {
  OFFSET=$1 perl -e '
    seek(STDIN, $ENV{OFFSET}, 0) || die "seek: $!\n"'
}

tell() {
  perl -le 'print tell(STDIN)'
}
   
{
  seek "${offset:-0}" || exit

  do-your-processing; ret=$?

  tell > "$offset_file" && exit "$ret"
} < "$file"
```

You'd want to make sure that whenever the file is truncated, the file.offset one is empty, truncated or 0 written to it.